# why need we add $path at the end when we config jdk variables in ubuntu;

Tags: ubuntu, java-home

When we config JDK environment varibales in Ubuntu.
We always do like this:
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
why need we add the $PATH??

Answer (score 1):

It appends the existing path to the end of the path you are setting. The snippet you gave is basically adding your java location to the beginning of your path.

Comment: Got it. Thanks, In brief, $PATH is calling a variable, it refers to the original system path. And in my situation, it stands for adding java location to the beginning as you said.